# Can anyone tell me the issue why some of the fields or entries are reflecting in a database and not reflecting in application

Tags: oracle11g

Can anyone tell me the issue why some of the  fields or entries  are reflecting in a database and not reflecting in application

When i run q query for a particular contracts in database i can see some of the accounting entries but those accounting entries are not reflecting in the front end application

Answer (score 0):

My *lucky guess* would be that you inserted rows in one session (e.g. using SQL Developer), but **DID NOT COMMIT**. Therefore, you see them while querying the table in the same session.

Front end application, on the other hand, doesn't "see" uncommitted changes.

What to do? Commit!

Answer (score 0):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data from another session (i.e. in your front-end application) then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client where you `INSERT`ed the data (i.e. SQL*Plus or SQL Developer).

*Note: even if you connect as the same user, this will create a separate session and you will not be able to see the uncommitted data in the other session.*

From the [`COMMIT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2):

> Until you commit a transaction:
>
> - You can see any changes you have made during the transaction by querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes. After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other users' statements that execute after the commit.
> - You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with the `ROLLBACK` statement (see `ROLLBACK`).